# I didn't find windows form application C# in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I can't find Windows form application in visual studio 2017.When I select C# and Windows, i can't find windows form application...Please help me

Comment: You probably did not select the option during installation. VS2017 does not install nearly everything like previous versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VS 2017, workloads to be downloaded needs to explicity selected. To install win forms workload, please follow following step

Launch visual studio installer -> click modify -> Select .Net desktop development workload -> click modify

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio) has exact steps